# Is there a way to write Regex in SQL Server query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am running a query on the SQL server. I need to get records where `LoginName` is starting with a given string and ending with integers. I am running the below query but it does not return any record. Let me know if this is not possible in SQL so I will handle in C# code.

```
SELECT * from TestTable where LoginName like 'Input[0-9]*%'
```

**Expected values:**

```
Input
Input1
Input123
```

**Not Expected values:**

```
Inputabc
abc
<empty string>
abcInput
```

Comment: SQL Server only supports basic pattern matching. If you require true Regex support, you'll need to look at CLR functions.

Comment: As for why you get no rows, that is because none of them start with `'Input'`, followed by a digit, followed by an asterisk (`*`). None of your expect results have a `'*'` in them. Seems you actually just want `LIKE 'Input[0-9]%'`.

Comment: @Larnu - `*` means "match zero to unlimited times" in regex syntax. So not valid in TSQL pattern

Comment: But, as I mentioned @MartinSmith , T-SQL does not support Regex, and `LIKE` will see `*` as a literal. Which is exactly why there are  no rows, as I said too.

Comment: yeah - I wasn't implying that you thought that `*` would work but your suggested `Input[0-9]` is not equivalent as that means "at least once"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to write Regex in SQL Server query?

Only by using CLR. There is no native support for regex. `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` support a very limited pattern matching dialect.

Nonetheless this is sufficient to get rows where `LoginName` is the string "Input" followed by any number of digits (including zero digits) then end of string.

As in the following ([DBFiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c06e88646d591cdb86ab1e431b6043b3))

```
SELECT *
FROM   TestTable
WHERE  LoginName LIKE 'Input%'
       AND SUBSTRING(LoginName, LEN('Input') + 1, 8000) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

- `LoginName LIKE 'Input%'` - LoginName starts with "Input"
- `SUBSTRING(LoginName, LEN('Input') + 1, 8000) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` - the substring after "Input" does not contain a character that is not in the range `0-9`

If you change the string to search for from `Input` remember to update both instances in the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212416/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-martin-smith).